# Отловить закрытие консольной программы

Tags: c#, консоль

Есть консольное приложение (C#), мне нужно отловить событие его закрытия. Это может быть и `Ctrl+C` и нажатие на крестик, вообще любое событие после которого программа закроется. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/474679/5752652

Comment: К ссылке выше - мне вполне хватило https://stackoverflow.com/a/25638275/3768545

Comment: Спасибо большое :)

Comment: @AK, а ответом запостить не хотите?, нехорошо же незакрытый топик. Да и потом придумают регулярку для удаления всех комментов, состоящих из одной ссылки...

Comment: @АндрейNOP, запостил ответ на свой вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо комментаторам выше, переведу содержание из ссылки.

В моей программе используется бесконечный цикл. Во-первых, мы можем под конец программы вставить метод, а можем, навсякий, добавить тригер на event закрытия сочетанием `^C`

```
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Добавляем слушатель события
        Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;
        while ( true )
        {
            // Наш бесконечный цикл
        }
        Console_CancelKeyPress(); // Навсякий (пожарный) случай пихаем это сюды.
        return 0; Может быть сюда программа не придет, но не факт
    }
    // Без нужных, слушателю событий, аргументов
    static void Console_CancelKeyPress()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
        // Termitate what I have to terminate
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
    // Делаем перегрузку метода, чтобы наш слушатель событий не выдавал ошибку
    static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Console_CancelKeyPress();
    }
}
```